# Jquery Selector- Getting a element based on attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am creating calendar type control with my html application and i have used table format to achive. In this calendar i have added the date attribute to td elements and my dom will like below

```
<td date="Tue Aug 30 2016" class="current">30</td>
<td date="Mon Aug 29 2016" class="current">29</td>
```

I have added the date attributes like this to all dates in that month calendar.

I want to use this date attribute with jQuery selector to retrive that particular td element. Also my date attribute value will get from below code

```
new Date("11/05/2016").toDateString(); // out will like "Sat Nov 05 2016"
```

I want select the elements some thing like this

```
$('.current[date=new Date("11/05/2016").toDateString()]')
```

// here i have set the 11/05/2016 manually but this will get from local storage variable.

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate:

```
$('.current-month[date="'+new Date("11/05/2016").toDateString()+'"]')
```

Comment: I am getting arror like this. Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .current-month[date=Fri Aug 26 2016]

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As `new Date("11/05/2016").toDateString()` needs to be executed, You need to concatenate the result in selector

```
$('.current-month[date="'+new Date("11/05/2016").toDateString()+'"]')
```

I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes to store arbitrary data.

```
<td data-date="Tue Aug 30 2016" class="current">30</td>
```

Comment: thanks but gettingSyntax error, unrecognized expression: .current-month[date=Fri Aug 26 2016]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

1. Create a function that loops through all td.current elements and compares the date data field with a supplied date.
2. When there is a match return that element.

   function getDateElement(date_selector) {
       $('td.current').each(function () {
           if($(this).data('date') === date_selector) {
               return $(this);
           }
       });
   }

   getDateElement('Tue Aug 30 2016');